# Anyone Using the Abyss Web Server

Tags: webserver

Just curious to see if anyone is using the Abyss Web Server for any projects.

http://www.aprelium.com/

I've checked it out a few times, had it running a few ASP.Net demo sites, but haven't gotten to far with it. I like the ease of use, but I'm thinking both IIS and Apache out class Abyss for the most part.

Has anyone used it?

If so, what is your experience?

I ask because I'm tempted to use if for some projects, but if it isn't worth the investment I probably won't.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Lame sauce closing this.  Not really opinion based if I'm asking if people used it and what their experience with it was.  Info fascist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No more than about 0.3% of public hosts, for sure:

http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2009/12/24/december_2009_web_server_survey.html

Comment: Huh, the sounds of silence :)  Thanks for the netcraft link.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is many years later, but Abyss is still around, and we are using it for some of our customers who must install our apps on desktops where their IT does not allow IIS to run.  It works well with MVC and .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: Good to know, does it handle routing without having to tweak your projects?  I was worried MVC routing was tied closely to the IIS pipeline, if it works without it awesome.

Comment: Yes, MVC and WebAPI routing works great, both traditional routing and attribute routing. :)

Comment: It is still around in 2023 and now available for MacOS and Linux as well. Well written, compact, great docs, solid support and easy to configure. An excellent local server and even good for some lightweight real world installations. 

Not quite NGINX but there are times when NGINX is OTT